Build Failure on Android After Upgrading React Native from 0.74.3 to 0.75.0 – Error in native_modules.gradle
I'm encountering a build issue after upgrading my React Native project from version 0.74.3 to 0.75.0. The problem occurs only on Android; everything works fine on iOS. Whenever I attempt to run any Android-related command (e.g., ./gradlew clean), I receive the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/mehmetsozd/Desktop/almiratur/almira_app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 418

* What went wrong:
Could not compile script '/Users/mehmetsozd/Desktop/almiratur/almira_app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  script '/Users/mehmetsozd/Desktop/almiratur/almira_app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle': 418: [Static type checking] - No such property: inputStream for class: java.lang.Process
   @ line 418, column 31.
               def output = process.inputStream.text.trim()
                                   ^
  
  script '/Users/mehmetsozd/Desktop/almiratur/almira_app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle': 418: [Static type checking] - No such property: text for class: java.lang.Object
   @ line 418, column 43.
     f output = process.inputStream.text.trim
                                   ^
  
  script '/Users/mehmetsozd/Desktop/almiratur/almira_app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle': 418: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#trim(). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
   @ line 418, column 24.
               def output = process.inputStream.text.trim()
                            ^
  
  3 errors


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUİLD FAILED in 332ms


Has anyone experienced a similar issue after upgrading React Native? What could be causing this, and how can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have the same problem, were you able to solve it?

I guess I couldn’t figure it out due to the changing Android structure, so instead, I took the Android folder from a new project and made the necessary configurations.

I dont have this problem when I do clean but I do have build problem on stripe related stuff for android
